# SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(string, certCollection, protocol, bool) won't send the certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I have a PEM certificate (the ones with **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----** and **-----END CERTIFICATE-----**) that should be sent to server for server requires client certification.

I know that it is said X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(string) does not support PEM and it only does DER but I actually get the information including public key, CN, Issuer, etc.

Anyway, my RemoteCertificationValidationCallBack does not get the certificate (it's null) even when I use t he DER (converted by openssl)

code on server

```
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(), false, (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            {
                return true;
            });
```

Can any of you guys help me understand why?

Thanks

Peyman